# parallel coord plot ggplot2 deprecated?

Tags: r, ggplot2, parallel-coordinates

When i try to make a parallel coordinate in ggplot2, i get the message that it is deprecated:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggpcp(mtcars) + geom_line()
```

Warning message:
'ggpcp' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")

however, the ggplot documentation did not say anything about this: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggpcp.html.

is there a new pcp function somewhere?

Comment: I can't recall any discussions about that, but if I had to guess, lots of things are being moved to other packages in order to simplify maintenance of ggplot2. In this case, there is a parallel coord plot function in GGally, so the thinking may have been to leave that functionality there.

Comment: That works! Never heard of GGally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Migrated to GGally. E.g.:

```
require(GGally)
ggparcoord(mtcars, columns = c(1, 5:10)) + geom_line()
```